# Numpy slicing given row for each column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an ... x n x m array, say `a`, where ... stands for an arbitrary number of additional dimensions. Let's call the n-dimension "rows" and the m-dimension" columns for simplicity, even though the array is higher-dimensional.

I also have a vector `v` of length n which contains indices for the last dimension (ranging from 0 to m-1). I would like to create an array `b` that uses this vector to extract the indicated column for each row.

One can easily do this using a loop. Here is a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.round(np.random.rand(2,3,4)*10)
v = [0, 2, 1]

print(a)
"""[[[ 1.  6.  9.  9.]
  [ 1.  8.  4. 10.]
  [ 0.  0.  5.  3.]]

 [[ 7.  8.  1. 10.]
  [ 7.  9.  7.  8.]
  [ 3.  4.  8.  7.]]]
"""

b = []
for i in range(len(v)):
    b.append(a.take(i, axis=-2).take(v[i], axis=-1))
b = np.asarray(b)

print(b)
"""
[[1. 7.]
 [4. 7.]
 [0. 4.]]
"""
```

Is there any smarter way to do this kind of indexing without looping?

Comment: Correct your example, there is a `7` in `b` that is not in `a`!

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi woops, forgot to copy half the `a` array. Fixed now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this will do the trick:

```py
a[..., np.arange(len(v)), v].T
```

In general, you can index through all dimensions using this syntax. In the above example, you select all elements in the first dimensions with `...`, then you select elements 0, 1, 2 in the second to last dimension (rows) with `np.arange(len(v))` and finally you select elements 0, 2, 1 in the last dimension (columns) with `v`. I am transposing the result with `T` in order to get the same dimensions as in `b`.

From the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding):

> Basic slicing with more than one non-: entry in the slicing tuple, acts like repeated application of slicing using a single non-: entry, where the non-: entries are successively taken (with all other non-: entries replaced by :). Thus, x[ind1, ..., ind2,:] acts like x[ind1][..., ind2, :] under basic slicing.

Comment: as it is high dimensional, not just limited to three dimensions, use `...` instead of `:`

Answer (score 0):

How about this, let's say `i` is (0,1,2) and `v` is (0,2,1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.round(np.random.rand(2,3,4)*10)
v = (0, 2, 1)

print(a)


i = (0, 1, 2)
ind = [slice(None)] * (a.ndim - 2) + [np.array(i), np.array(v)]
k = a[tuple(ind)]
transpose_dim = [a.ndim-2]+  list(range(0, a.ndim-2)) 
k = k.transpose(transpose_dim)

print(k)
```

This `[slice(None)] * (a.ndim - 2)` gets `a[:,:,.....]` until the last two dims from `a` and `[np.array(i), np.array(v)]` selects the right indices from every row. Then you have to convert the rows of `k` to columns with `transpose`.

This works for variable dimensions, for OP's test case and other test cases I ran.

Comment: You should test this against the OP example.  Your `ind` needs to be a `tuple`.  You also need an `arange`, e.g. `ind = tuple([slice(None)] * (a.ndim - 2) + [np.arange(3), np.array(v)])`.  Constructing a general indexing tuple like this is a bit messy, but the idea is used in several `numpy` functions that need to handle general cases.

Comment: You are right. Even though it runs correctly on my system, I do get a warning about `ind` needing to be a `tuple` in the future. I have fixed it. I did run the code against OP's example, I will post the edited snippet :)

Comment: Yes, this is an area where `numpy` has been cleaningup usage.